# Laravel vue with two different layout

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I that possible to have different layout in laravel vue components?

If we use blades all we need is to change `@extends('layouts.app')` to `@extends('layouts.custom')` and then you have different design, but how it's working in vuejs?

## Code

This is my `App.vue` file which is in charge of rendering template of all pages

```
<template>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          //navbar
        </nav>
        <el-container>
            <el-header>Header</el-header>

            <el-container>
                <el-aside width="200px">
                    <h5>{{site_name}}</h5>
                </el-aside>

                <el-main>
                    <a class="sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#content">Skip to main content</a>
                    <div>
                        <transition name="fade">\
                            //router which renders all components in this part
                            <router-view id="content" :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
                        </transition>
                    </div>
                </el-main>
            </el-container>

            <el-footer>Footer</el-footer>
        </el-container>
    </div>
</template>
```

and here is my layout blade file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>

        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
        <script>
            window.default_locale = "{{ config('app.locale') }}";
            window.fallback_locale = "{{ config('app.fallback_locale') }}";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Basically that `aside` part in `app.vue` i only need to show in admin part not front-end (for users)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a prop to your component
Something like:

Blade File:

```
@php
$isLoggedIn = Auth::check();
@endphp

<my-component :is-logged-in="{{ $isLoggedIn }}" </<my-component>
```

Comment: that way even ordinary users can see that. this is only for admin panel part not for all logged users

Comment: also even if we restrict loggedin users to admin those admins will see this sidebar in admin panel as well as front-end part (it's only belong to admin panel)

Comment: Why not create a two version of app.vue ? Like that in your blade you just make a condition like if this is the URL then I will show this app1.vue or else app2.vue. so on this approach . Front users cannot even show the sidebar unless you have redirected to admin site

Comment: @Qonvex620 my blade file only provides `id="app"` if we want to make such condition we should make it in `app.vue` itself not to make it duplicate, either way there is unanswered question: `how to let router know which route should use which condition?`